# How to split varchar in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a procedure in where I am taking the input parameters as array of strings.

This String contains like `5-Deal deleted`

I want to split this `varchar` into 5 and Deal deleted.
Here split conditions is `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `regexp_substr`:

```
select regexp_substr ('5-Deal deleted' , '[^-]+', 1, rownum) split
      from dual
      connect by level <= length (regexp_replace ('5-Deal deleted' , '[^-]+'))  + 1;
```

Then you can use `BULK COLLECT INTO` for store into a variable

Comment: Too much resource consuming.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple task, I would go with `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`. `REGULAR EXPRESSION` would be too much resource consuming.

`INSTR` would find the position of `-`, i.e. hyphen, and `SUBSTR` would pick the required portion of the string.

Or,

If your example data is what it looks like for all the rows, then, just extract `DIGIT` and `ALPHA` from the string and just `concatenate` them. This would obviously need `REGULAR EXPRESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT SUBSTR ('5-Deal deleted', 1, INSTR ('5-Deal deleted', '-') - 1)
          AS FIRST,
       SUBSTR ('5-Deal deleted', INSTR ('5-Deal deleted', '-') + 1) AS second
  FROM DUAL
```